# python decorators property: getter/setter

Tags: python, api, append, decorator

I have this code that I'm trying to use **decorators getters and setters to append** a simple list that receives data from an API.
However the **list is coming empty**, I've tried out a lot of examples but I just cant seem to get it right.

```
import requests
from typing import Dict, List

headers_ = {
    'sm-token': '{"Location":{"Latitude":-23.551548099999998,"Longitude":-46.6331008},"IdClientAddress":0,"IsDelivery":false,"IdLoja":2691,"IdRede":884,"DateBuild":"2022-06-08T00:09:36.738357"}',
}

class Scraper:
    def __init__(self):
        self.session = requests.Session()
        self.header = {'sm-token': '{"Location":{"Latitude":-23.551548099999998,"Longitude":-46.6331008},'
                                   '"IdClientAddress":0,"IsDelivery":false,"IdLoja":2691,"IdRede":884,"DateBuild":'
                                   '"2022-06-08T00:09:36.738357"}'}
        self.category_list = ['bebidas', 'bebidas-alcoolicas']
        self.market_id = [2691]
        self.sub_categ_list = []

    def sub_categories(self) -> List:
        url_sub_categ = (f'https://b2c-api-premiumlabel-production.azurewebsites.net/api/b2c/page/'
                         f'menu?id_loja={self.market_id[0]}')

        for dep in self.session.get(url_sub_categ, headers=self.header).json()['departments']:  # ['departments']
            self.sub_categ_list.append((dep['imagem_url'], dep['categories']))  # self.sub_categ_list  # sub_categ_list

    # def aaa(self):
    #     ab = self.sub_categories()
    #     return ab

    @property
    def sub_categ_list(self):
        print('getter')
        return self._sub_categ_list

    @sub_categ_list.setter
    def sub_categ_list(self, valor):
        valor = [str(x).replace('4', '40') for x in valor]
        print('setter')
        self._sub_categ_list = valor

scrape = Scraper()
# print(scrape.sub_categories())  # original function OK
print(scrape.sub_categ_list)  # decorator value empty
# print(scrape.aaa())  # function called directly, I heard that it is not a good practice
```

If you uncomment the line with function "def aaa(self)" and print it, you're gonna see this one works (as the well the original function also works), but I don't want to call the function directly from another function such as "aaa".

Obs: I have knowledge until functions, never tried out classes or decorators, I'm building my first OOP project, so ANY advice or changes to the code are very welcome, I just want to start learning the right way to do OOP.

The purpose of this project is retrieving data from API, some data cleanings, creating data frame with pandas and store it somewhere.

Comment: Well, you are just initializing a new `Scraper()`, which make `self.sub_categ_list = []` an empty list (btw you should do: `self._sub_categ_list = []`), an then asking for that list in `scrape.sub_categ_list`, that will be empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `__init__` function sets the property to `[]`.  So just creating `scape = Scraper()` will only generate an empty list.  Printing the property after that returns the empty list as expected.

If you want to populate the list on creation, use the following in `__init__`:

```py
self.sub_categ_list = self.sub_categories()
```

Then change the `sub_categories` function to return the populated list so it is assigned to the property:

```py
    def sub_categories(self) -> List:
        url_sub_categ = (f'https://b2c-api-premiumlabel-production.azurewebsites.net/api/b2c/page/'
                         f'menu?id_loja={self.market_id[0]}')

        result = []
        for dep in self.session.get(url_sub_categ, headers=self.header).json()['departments']:  # ['departments']
            result.append((dep['imagem_url'], dep['categories']))  # self.sub_categ_list  # sub_categ_list
        return result
```

Also, a note about the "right way to do OOP".  Returning an internal mutable member variable of the class instance isn't a good idea.  Doing something like the following inadvertently modified the internal `s._sub_categ_list` list as well, because `x` is a reference to the *same* list.

```py
s = Scraper()
x = s.sub_categ_list
x.append(5)
```

You're better off calling `s.sub_categories()` where it returns a new list each time like I've defined it above.

Comment: Thank you very much, works perfectly.

Just one doubt about the statement above:
I'm just wondering now that you said that is not good to call "s.sub_categ_list" because it's mutating something that shouldn't being muted. 

But if I'm using getter and setters to modify my list, I'll have to necessarily call "s.sub_categ_list", in this case, what do you recommend, avoid using decorator @property with list, or do u have another suggestion?

Comment: @gimmedata In this case I'd skip the property and just use `sub_categories()` to return a new list when needed.  Why would you need a setter anyway?  Do you want the user of the class to set that property to some arbitrary value?

Comment: Exactly, it'll need to set an arbitrary value, but if there's some way to skip it, I surely will.

Comment: @gimmedata In that case, a safe way of implementing the property would be to set or return a deepcopy of the list, to avoid the aliasing problem shown at the end of my answer, but as long as you know the risks....